# How to use try_files to bypass 404 HTTP error

Tags: nginx, nginx-config

I would like to parse the HTTP error code 404 (not found) response to the client by having some kind of static content, instead of having the 404 page. Can this be done by fallback scenario, using *try_files*, and having a response HTTP 200 to the client?

If request is made for /blahblah, the first location will initially get the request and try to find a file called blahblah in /var/www/main directory.

If request cannot find one, it will follow up by searching for a file called *blahblah.html*. It will then try to see if there is a directory called blahblah/ within the /var/www/main directory.

Failing all of these attempts, it will redirect to /fallback/index.html. This will trigger another location search that will be caught by the second location block. This will serve the file /var/www/another/fallback/index.html.

is this feasible by having this kind of configuration?

```
root /var/www/main;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ /fallback/index.html;
}
location /fallback {
    root /var/www/another;
}
```

Comment: One option is to redirect a 404 to your 'custom' error page:  `error_page 404 /custom_404.html;` [Docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#error_page)

Comment: but this redirection will not have a HTTP 200 to the client response.

Comment: I believe you can override that like so: `error_page 404 =200 /custom.html;`. (Sorry, no server to test). Edit: It's included in the docs; Furthermore, it is possible to change the response code to another using the “=response” syntax ...

Comment: Your question contains a requirement and a perfectly valid solution. Other than, yes your configuration's fine, is there a question?

Comment: if it valid, I can proceed to the closure.